# Unable to execute sys.fn_get_audit_file() procedure in Azure Synaspe Serverless Pool

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

Unable to execute sys.fn_get_audit_file() function in  Azure Synaspe Serverless Pool. The procedure fails with ERROR

> VIEW SERVER SECURITY AUDIT permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'.

Granted view server state and control permission to the SQL user.

```
use db1;
GRANT CONTROL TO testuser;

use master;
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO testuser;
```

Still facing the similar error. when trying to execute procedure with SQL user.

Note- I'm able to run the function using Azure AD user but not with SQL user.

Any addition information required for sql user to execute sys.fn_audit_file() function?

Comment: Does https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/199449 answer your question? CONTROL is a db permission while CONTROL SERVER is server level

Comment: @siggemannen, Control server permission worked. Thanks!!

Comment: If issue resolved, can you post it as answer to help other community members.

Comment: @PratikLad good call, posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/199449 answer your question? CONTROL is a db permission while CONTROL SERVER is server level one